# Is "ut" or "est" in the following sentence necessary?

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation

This is probably a basic question but I am looking for a little help translating "death to bad memories". I come up with either; *mors ut malum memorias* or *Mors est malis memorias*.

My own thought is **ut** which can be used as **to**. Or Is it possible to translate it to *memoriam malorum mortem* not using ut or est at all?

Which is the correct form? And even more importantly why is it the correct form?  Am I off by miles with my attempted translation? Any help will of course be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first I also thought this was a basic question, but I think it is actually not that easy to answer.

Let us first look at your suggestions. I am afraid the answer to your question: “Am I off by miles?” is yes. You are on the right path with the three words *mors*, *malus* and *memoria* but beyond that, frankly, the sentences look like a leisurely but somewhat aimless walk through the declension table ;)

A bad memory is *mala memoria*. Actually I suspect that rather means “bad memory” in the sense that someone cannot remember things well. In any event I would prefer a more expressive word like *tristis memoria*, which means a sad/unhappy/depressing memory. The plural is *tristes memoriae*.

Now my first impulse was: The English “death to X” should be expressed with the Latin dative, yielding:

> Mors tristibus memoriis.

And I am pretty certain an ancient Roman would understand that, just as a medieval monk would. But it seems to me this is not the idiomatic way to express the idea in Latin; at least I could find no example older than the motto of an [American air force unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/107th_Fighter_Squadron).

A more typical Latin expression would be *Perea(n)t X*, which is, for example, found in the famous song [*Gaudeamus igitur*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaudeamus_igitur):

> Pereat tristitia,
> Pereant osores.
>
> *Down with sadness,
>
> Down with the haters.*

So I would ultimately suggest this form:

> **Pereant tristes memoriae.**

Literally: “May unhappy memories perish.” Like “perish” in English, the verb *perire* strongly suggests death.

Comment: Excellent answer! The correction makes a lot more sense and the explanation even more ;) Your suggestion has put me on a path to look at Latin in another way. My thanks! I will wait a little longer to give other answers a chance but I consider this question answered by you.

Comment: Great anwer! Your observation that *malae memorial* means good at forgetting is spot on. I also have no objection to your translation. However, I'd like to add that *memoria malorum* might be closer to what the original poster meant by a bad memory. If that's true. then *pereant memoriae malorum* might serve you just as well as *tristes memorial*.